# Best Practices for Roaming Profile Support Testing

Tags: windows, testing, roaming-profile

We need to ensure that a Windows app that we make (which includes Office plugins) works right when installed in a Roaming Profile environment. Can anyone supply procedures, or a pointer to procedures, for

1. Setting up a test AD domain for use in testing with roaming profiles
2. testing

The fact that we've got Office plugins implies, of course, that we've got COM objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the proper configuration of Active Directory I would look at a post over on ServerFault as that is more of a server configuration item.

From a testing standpoint, your test operation is quite simple.

1. Install it on one machine
2. Validate that it is functional
3. Login to the other machine and validate that the process is still working.

Now, all of this is a bit limited depending on how the roaming profiles are setup, as many times, installed applications are not going to be coming across, their configuration/options obviously will as they are stored in the roaming profile of the user, but the application itself must be installed on each machine, once installed, then settings/options are there across the board.

*NOTE*

This test scenario does assume that a user with a roaming profile has the same permissions to access every machine on the domain.  If you are in an environment where users might have limited permission sets depending on the machine that they login to, you will need to modify the above criteria to include testing on each of the "limited access" machines in addition to a full access machine.

Comment: I do have a question running on sf related to this, though another would be reasonable. We got hit with a registry ACL mystery on just one computer when we tried the simple plan, so I was led to wonder if anyone has a more complicated plan.

Comment: My guess then is that you have users with roaming profiles that have different permission sets depending on the machines that they are executing?